# Using java 8 CompletableFuture in a recursive manner

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, completable-future

I have a need to load records from a database and then perform in a chain some actions on them and i want to refactor our existing code to take advantage of the CompletableFuture API

the basic idea is

1. a.load records into a queue
   b.for each records in the queue do:

   1. perform task A (takes a certain while)
   2. perform task B (takes even more time) based on task A
   3. perform task C (also takes time)

some records of course end sooner than the others,  so i want that as soon as one is complete, another one (from the queue) will start execution

i have the following code

```
gamesQueue = new PriorityQueue<Game>();
completable = new LinkedList<CompletableFuture<String>>();
Instant start = Instant.now();
Executor pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
DB.getInstance().getConn().useHandle(handle -> {
   handle.attach(GameService.class).list().stream().forEach(game -> gamesQueue.add(game));
});
```

this will load my records
then im doing the following

```
while (!gamesQueue.isEmpty()) {

        CompletableFuture<String> step1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getCurrentGame, pool)
                .thenApply(CapitalLetterTask::capitalize).thenApply(game-> {
                    if(game.isEndedExceptionaly()) {
                        handleNumber5Exception(game);
                        throw new CompletionException(new NumberFiveException(game, "got number 5"));
                    }
                    return game;
                })
                .thenApply(AddStarTask::addStarToGame).exceptionally(ExceptionHandler::handleWeirdEx);
        completable.add(step1);

    }


    while (!completable.isEmpty()) {
        CompletableFuture<String> completed = completable.poll();
        if (completed.isDone()) {
            try {
                log.debug("result: {}", completed.get());
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        } else if(completed.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
            try{ //never enters here
                log.debug("This is a bad result:{} ", completed.get());
            }catch(Exception ex) {

            }

        }
         else {
            completable.add(completed);
        }
    }
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
    log.debug("Total time: {}", duration.getSeconds());
    loadGames();  <-- call itself
}
```

im not content with my exception handling moreover im seeing that even futures that were supposed to be caught in the first stage are still being passed further down the chain

what i would like to ask is how to implement it in such a way that each method can throw its own custom exception, caught and handled without passing it further down the chain